# Apache beehive and localizing default pager for DataGrid

Tags: java, apache, localization, beehive, netui

I am trying to localize strings created by Apache Beehive and netui default pager.

I'd like to translate language of this output.

```
Page 1 of 3  First / Previous   Next / Last
```

My .jsp code looks something like this

```
<netui-data:dataGrid name="searchResultsGrid" dataSource="pageInput.someData">

  <netui-data:header>
       ...
  </netui-data:header>
  <netui-data:rows>
       ...
  </netui-data:rows>
  <netui-data:configurePager pagerFormat="firstPrevNextLast" pageAction="refresh" pageSize="10"
    disableDefaultPager="false" />
</netui-data:dataGrid>
```

I already found [keys](http://beehive.apache.org/docs/1.0.1/netui/apidocs/javadoc/org/apache/beehive/netui/databinding/datagrid/api/rendering/IDataGridMessageKeys.html) I should use in translation, but how I configure message properties file(s) that the pager should use?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, `IDataGridMessageKeys` is merely an exposed internal interface, not really meant to be used by end-users. As a guess, I'd wager they had to expose it as public from within that package in order for other packages to be able to use it, and couldn't find another way (with their build scheme) to safely pass it to the rest of the code.

(Of course, I might be wrong. I'll try rooting through the source some more.)